# Garbled keys: Any ideas for fixing a bizarre keyboard driver problem on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, drivers

One of my kids was doing what she always does on the PC (Windows 7, about two months old), and the keyboard stopped working. I replaced it, and get the same behavior on both machines:

```
type:   you get:
a       a
b       gtv
c       dec
d       dec
e       dec
f       gtv
g       gtv
h       jun
i       i
j       jun
k       dec
l       [-l
m       m
n       jun
o       [-l
p       p
q       q
r       r
s       <nothing>
t       gtv
u       jun
v       gtv
w       ws
x       <nothing>
y       y
z       <nothing>
```

digits work fine
most punctuation is bad too

The MS troubleshooter utility (Mats_run.devices.exe) found nothing.

The system is set for the en-US keyboard.

The on-screen keyboard works fine, which is how I managed to log back in.

I can't find keyboard drivers on Microsoft's site, and I don't want to download
a friggin keyboard driver from some dodgy 3rd-party site.  Is there a better way
to fix this,or is it a job for Roto Rooter?

Comment: You shouldn't have given him/her access to Emacs ;) Is it a USB or a PS/2 style keyboard?

Comment: They're both PS/2 keyboards.  However.... I checked the registry this morning for any weird startup keys, and found nothing. Then looked at the last AVG report, and see that it installed an update yesterday at 6:15 PM, which is very likely the last system-changing event.  I'll go check the AVG site.

Comment: I don't think a PS/2 keyboard would have a specialized driver per se (aside from the one that the OS comes with).  It's curious that the combinations that are occurring together are in physical proximity on the keyboard.  Beyond that, though, it could be a short in the connector on the motherboard.  See if borrowing a USB keyboard helps, as that would definitely point to something with the PS/2 connector (or on the motherboard).

Comment: USB keyboards work fine. I'll have to find out if the machine is still under warantee.